# Forbid number property for string-typed index signature

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have a type definition like

```js
type Foo = {
    [_: string]: number
}
```

But we can assign an object with a numbered property to this type:

```js
const foo: Foo = {
    10: 42
}
```

**Question**: Is there any way (compiler options or something) to forbid this behavior? i.e., I want to forbid assigning numbered properties into a string-typed index signature.

(Note)
[The "indexable types" section of the official typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) says "when indexing with a number, JavaScript will actually convert that to a string before indexing into an object" and I know this is why such assignments are accepted. I want to know how to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation you cited](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

> It is possible to support both types of indexers, but the type returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned from the string indexer.

Consider [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never):

> The `never` type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, `never` (except `never` itself).

That suggests that you can redefine `Foo` as:

```
type Foo = {
    [_: string]: number
    [_: number]: never
}
```

This means: all `string`-valued keys should have a `number` property type, and all `number`-valued keys should have a `never` property type.  Since you can't ever make a valid `never` type (no type is assignable to it), any attempt to use a numeric key will give you an error:

```
const goodFoo: Foo = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}

const badFoo: Foo = {
    eight: 8,
    nine: 9,
    10: 42 // error!
    // number is not assignable to never
};
```

Looks good to me.  Note that this has the side-effect of prohibiting "numeric string indices" also:

```
const alsoBad: Foo = { // error!
    eight: 8,
    nine: 9,
    "10": 42 
}
//   Property '"10"' is incompatible with index signature.
```

Hopefully that doesn't matter much, since as you noted, at runtime `{10: 42}` and `{"10": 42}` are the same thing.

Hope that helps give you some direction; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKCjqBtAfQC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwF0SaBXAWwCMIKtd9iorTtyaCIAN25YAvlCxYAxnBrkodBABN4cEtuRpeuAIYkAjABpDODiQBMl7LgUkAzDN6Llqjka0JdCPoYjjgQVHQAFsAkABwOfDS0ECQAnPG4pgAMJAAstlAA9AVQ3BRwFACEVoXFQlwUUFSkgnDAUEakpOE0RhwANtDAiDQSUpjSANzymEoqbUZ9pHAAQr4BiCioNSUUZZXVYZHRUHHViSOp6TgARFnXufnumEW4AAplkBSgUADkt5nXH6NZq0JRsMBGYBUfrQADuVGAEUaNA0EAAHmRupCWBQIAA6IA)

Comment: Thank you for the great idea! It never crossed my mind at all. However, I didn't see why the "numeric string indices" are also rejected. Is `"10"` recognized as a `number` value? Could you give me the specification behind this behavior?

Comment: The (increasingly outdated) TypeScript spec [says](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/136f728bb011ecf1bbf0ff2aac6dacc5cb6568cb/doc/spec.md#222-property-names): Numeric literal property names are equivalent to string literal property names with the string representation of the numeric literal, as defined in the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!