# Why is a number a valid key of `{ [key: string]: unknown; }`?

Tags: typescript

```ts
function Foo<DataType extends { [_: string]: unknown }>(name: keyof DataType) {
  return name;
}

Foo<{"name":"Tom",1:string}>(1);   // why is this not an error?
```

What happened here?  I think a number key is supposed to be an error.

Comment: @jcalz I don't think this assigns 1 to the full object, rather it uses it as a keyof the object, which intuitively should only be string. What you said is very insightful but perhaps not directly applicable to this question, I don't think. Useful information nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question 

Comment: Yes, i dont know why  take a number as a key can success,thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript roughly treats numeric keys as a *special type of string key*.

That's because in JavaScript, all non-`symbol` [property keys are coerced to `string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#property_names).  In the [TypeScript documentation for index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) it references this somewhat obliquely by mentioning that a `number` index signature property type must be compatible with a `string` index signature:

> It is possible to support both types of indexers, but the type returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned from the string indexer. This is because when indexing with a `number`, JavaScript will actually convert that to a `string` before indexing into an object. That means that indexing with `100` (a `number`) is the same thing as indexing with `"100"` (a `string`), so the two need to be consistent.

Indeed, starting with [TypeScript 2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types), the [`keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) when applied to a type with a `string` index signature will return `number` as well as `string`:

```
type X = keyof { [_: string]: unknown };
// type X = string | number
```

This isn't completely accurate or consistent, and there are some weird edge cases elsewhere in the language (`"1" extends keyof {1: string}` is false, and so is `1 extends keyof {"1": string}`, yet you can access either key on an object of either type:

```
let k1: keyof { 1: string };
k1 = 1; // okay
k1 = "1"; // error
declare const o1: { 1: string };
o1[1]; // okay
o1["1"]; // okay

let k2: keyof { "1": string };
k2 = 1; // error
k2 = "1"; // error
declare const o2: { "1": string };
o2[1]; // okay
o2["1"]; // okay
```

But those are secondary effects.  If you *need* to reject numeric keys for some reason, then you can look at the question and answer at [Forbid number property for string-typed index signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62506068/2887218).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBADTgXjgaxhA9gMzgbzgG0B9ALjgGcwAnASwDsBzAXQoFcG0GsB3BuAF8A3KAD0YuJFiIUVWoyZwAPnABy7ALYAjGDQDCWBtRrsAxmCw1QNkABsYYdAEYKGbHkKv59ZkNEgaM5yzsJwEnBYaACGEKBBcgBEzolhEXo0VqAAJjBmdtE08GZG1JHeXhQmiv6gWM5EzixpklGxdQ3Jic3hrTFxIKAOTmgATG6YuARwXVUKfiLxoyEtcBlZgcuoXavr1iC5+YXFpU5Y49OzPjWLIOeNPRFtA-ddj33tg19AA)

Answer (score 0):

It does not accept any number but only `1`:

```js
Foo<{"name":"Tom",1:string}>(2); // will give an error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQNbwPYDMoG8BEAdgIYC2EeAXHgCrol4A0AjBQM7ABOAlgQOYC%20AKAD0wqOIB6AfkGDMAVwIBjYF3QEoAMXToAPABEiwItXDQIAD2AQCAE1a4oAbTQgKUdtz4Bdd0QII-AB8ABTEZO6uWFCGxqaQAJQ4guIcEMDyHBrhEADcgkKC2nr4OZQ0dIwsnjwCoQBMCblQolAA7gAWCMAdXA4E6MBQEBwc6BwAdCJi4rNz8wsL0kA)

Moreover, the type Typescript deduces from your object type is `"name" | 1`:

```js
type Key = keyof {"name":"Tom",1:string}
//   ^? type Key = "name" | 1
```

[Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) indicates that `string`, `number`, `symbol`, template string patterns, and union types consisting only of these are allowed as keys.